# AFNetworking Older version without arc

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I want to download AFNetwoking's older version without arc please guide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not use ARC in your project you can add the -fobjc-arc flag to all the AFNetworking source files to compile only those under ARC. You can set these flags in the "Compile Sources" part of the Build Phases tab in  the project settings.

You can also go to the GitHub [tags](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tags) and download version 0.10.1.

Comment: Thnks but i know that i have to provide support for 4.3 and am looking for 0.10.x release.